# Annotation in Preview under Yosemite: How to get back the old behaviour?

Tags: macos, pdf, preview

I am using Yosemite (OS X 10.10) on my MacBook Air mid 2011.

In the version 10.9 and before, annotation (making strokes or arrows) worked liked this:

1. Selecting the form you want to draw
2. Select the colour you want to use
3. AND THEN you can draw it by hand

The new behaviour is:

1. Choose the form you want to draw
2. And then, it's immediately there.

You have to move the form to the exact position and have no chance to draw it like in 10.9.

> Is this a bug or where can i go back to the old behaviour?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? This is super annoying.

Comment: No, not yet. I guess this is the new behaviour now...